# Grouping relatively close values using LINQ or loop

Tags: linq, loops, linq-group

I guess this would be more maths than C#. I've got an array of float values, where most values belong to one of the few tightly packed ranges. Here's an example (Lower Limit=0,Upper Limit=612):

```
3.4,5.0,6.1, 
144.0,144.14,145.0,147.0, 
273.77,275.19,279.0, 
399.4,399.91,401.45, 
533.26,537.0,538.9
```

This is a single array of 16 values, just separated them to show those "groups". What I need to do is to somehow group them, either using Linq, or a manual loop or whatever, so that those close values fall in a single group.

A simple math operation like dividing by 10 (or 100) won't work, because 399 would fall in a different group than 401 (4th group in the above example). Another approach would be to create a histogram of some kind, but I'm looking for something simple here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So what output do you expect from the input example you have given?

Comment: something like this:

1 3.4
1 5.0
1 6.1
1 144.0
2 144.14
2 145.0
2 147.0
3 273.77

and so on.

Comment: Are you asking how to determine what group each number will be in? If so, how many groups will there be? How many items will there be? What are your criteria for clustering?

Comment: well, criteria for clustering is somewhat fuzzy, but we can see above that those values are "clearly" packed in some very close ranges.

Comment: I can't seem to add "carriage return" in the comments. There is a CR after every float value in the above comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just an another idea of a clustering with using `GroupBy` with a custom comparer

```
var numbers = new float[]
    {
       3.4f, 5.0f, 6.1f, 144.0f, 144.14f, 145.0f, 
       147.0f, 273.77f, 275.19f, 279.0f, 399.4f, 399.91f, 401.45f,
       49, 50, 51,
       533.26f, 537.0f, 538.9f
    };

foreach (var group in numbers.GroupBy(i => i, new ClosenessComparer(4f)))
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", group));
```

And the custom `ClosenessComparer`:

```
public class ClosenessComparer : IEqualityComparer<float>
{
    private readonly float delta;

    public ClosenessComparer(float delta)
    {
        this.delta = delta;
    }

    public bool Equals(float x, float y)
    {
        return Math.Abs((x + y)/ 2f - y) < delta;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(float obj)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

And the output:

```
1: 3,4 5 6,1
2: 144 144,14 145 147
3: 273,77 275,19 279
4: 399,4 399,91 401,45
6: 49 50 51
5: 533,26 537 538,9
```

Comment: What's the significance of 2 in `Math.Abs((x + y)/ 2f - y)` ?

Comment: @ramesh For others looking, "(x + y) / 2" is taking the average of x and y

Comment: @alias65536 - got it. it is basically `Avg(X,Y)-Y`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a method that groups elements if they're within a certain delta (4 by default) of the previous value:

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<double>> GetClusters(IEnumerable<double> data,
                                             double delta = 4.0)
{
    var cluster = new List<double>();
    foreach (var item in data.OrderBy(x=>x))
    {
        if (cluster.Count > 0 && item > cluster[cluster.Count - 1] + delta)
        {
            yield return cluster;
            cluster = new List<double>();
        }
        cluster.Add(item);
    }
    if (cluster.Count > 0)
        yield return cluster;
}
```

You can get tweak the algorithm by changing what you use for `cluster[cluster.Count - 1] + delta`. For example, you might use

- `cluster[0] + delta` - delta from first element in the cluster
- `cluster.Average() + delta` - delta from the mean of the cluster so far
- `cluster[cluster.Count / 2] + delta` - delta from the median of the cluster so far

Comment: what would .OrderBy(x=>x) do?

Comment: @dotNET: That `OrderBy` sorts the items in ascending order. That way it can always be assured that each item will be greater than or equal to the previous item without you having to pass in a sorted list.

Comment: This seems like an acceptable solution. Let me check it on my end and get back. I'll mark it as answer if we don't get a better answer by then.